# C# Using MS Acess Database in Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, database, forms, ms-access

i've made a program which contains 3 forms. i have used Microsoft Access Database in the first form and it worked perfectly here is the code i used.

```
       public partial class newRegisteration : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public newRegisteration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\OmarS_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\School System\School System\School.accdb;
    Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into School ([Name], [Age], [Grade], [Class]) VALUES('" + nameTextBox2.Text + "', '" + ageTextBox2.Text + "', '" + gradeTextBox2.Text + "', '" + classTextBox2.Text + "') ";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            Clipboard.SetText(ex.ToString());
        }
    }        
}
```

now in the second form, when i drag the grid view  database to the form from the data source it doesn't work although it works with the first form. and i tried writing codes to call the Grid view for the database but it didn't work too all i get is empty columns for the Database and no code is written in the code page. and when i do copy the codes and modify it to match with the new form it gets error unexpected handler. so how can i fix this ?
how can i use the database with same connection more that once ?

PS : I tried doing another connection to the same database didn't work as well.

EDIT : the second form code

```
      private void CurrentStudents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                         
        using (OleDbConnection connection2 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\OmarS_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\School System\School System\School.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")) 
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from School", connection2);
            OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            olda.Fill(dt);
            schoolDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            schoolDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that your database is locked at one of the forms. You should try accessing your connection in USING block so you'll not need to close or dispose your connection object explicitly.

```
using (OleDbConnection  connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\OmarS_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\School System\School System\School.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                //Your code goes here
            }
```

Comment: i used this code for the first form and it worked as usual but the second form still has it's problem for now.

Comment: sorry it didn't work at the beginning but now it worked so good :D thank you.